# Aplicar estilos a lista de opciones select

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Tengo un problema intento inspeccionar la lista de opciones de un select, para aplicar los estilos, pero al inspeccionar la lista de opciones en el html no aparece como tal, entonces como puedo apicar estilos a la lista de opciones de un select?

HTML Bootstrap 5:

```
<select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
  <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

Como se muestra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero cambiar es el hover azul que se despliega en la primera opcion por otro color y quiero ajustar el ancho de la lista de opciones al tamaño del select principal, hay manera de hacerlo?

Comment: Según la [documentación](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/select/) (supongo que sabes que existe una documentación que es la fuente de conocimiento inicial, gratuita y legible, y no [es.so]) **NO puedes** modificar el estilo de los elementos `<option>` debido a las limitaciones del navegador. Existen variables SASS que podrías usar para establecer tus condiciones iniciales para el elemento `<select>`, pero no para los elementos `<option>`. Saludos

Comment: Comprendo, la otra podria sería customizar un componente por ejemplo un radio o una lista, y hacerlo pasar como select, de esa forma tengo más control de estas etiquetas